# How to exit a script in python

Tags: python, exit

how can I shut down script in python?
    `sys.exit()` 
does not work.. so where the problem is?
Edit: changed indentation as in my file
    import sys
    def sifra():
        retezec = input("Zadejte slovo: ")
        print("Zadali jste slovo: ",retezec)
        zprava = ""
        posun = int(input("Zadejte číslo o kolik se má šifra posouvat: "))

```
    for znak in retezec:
        i = ord(znak)
        i = i + posun
        if (i > ord("z")):
            i = i - 26
        znak = chr(i)
        zprava = zprava + znak
    print("Zašifrovaná zpráva: ", zprava)

    znovu = input("Znovu? A/N ")
    if(znovu == "A" or "a"):
        sifra()
    elif(znovu == "N" or "n"):
        sys.exit()
    else:
        pass
sifra()
```

Comment: Are you **sure** you are getting to `sys.exit()`?

Comment: @Idos I'm sure he's not (or I would be if the code was correctly indented).

Comment: Your definition for function `sifra` is not properly writen, please indent it properly.

Comment: `znovu == "N" or "n"` doesn't do what you expect

Comment: Try `exit(0)` with out `sys`

Comment: `quit()` is another option

Comment: One way to resolve this is to do `znovu.upper() == "A"` and `znovu.upper() == "N"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`znovu == "N" or "n"` is not what you want. You need to compare `znovu` to both these values:

```
elif (znovu == 'N') or (znovu == 'n'):
    sys.exit()
```

Another alternative would be the one suggested in the comments or simply:

```
elif znovu in 'Nn': sys.exit()
```

Assuming that nobody inputs 'Nn' as an answer, but even if they (accidentally) do so, this can still be considered as 'No'.

Comment: Alternatively: ```elif znovu in ['N', 'n']:```

Comment: If I use `elif (znovu == 'N') or (znovu == 'n'):
    sys.exit()` program immediately closes and in cmd error is "unindent does not match any outer indentation level" and if I corret the `if(znovu == "A" or "a"):
        sifra()` to `if(znovu == 'A') or (znovu == 'a'):
        sifra()` the error is same

Comment: @pandik70, make sure you're not mixing tabs and spaces in your code

Comment: @ForceBru do you know any way to check it out?

Comment: @pandik70, well, if your code isn't too huge, you can create a new file and rewrite it there (don't copy and paste!). You could also write a new Python script that reads a file and outputs its contents through the `repr` function and make it run through your code: it will output `\\t` if it finds a tab and a blank space if it finds a space. Then check whether there are mixed spaces & tabs and edit these mixes away.

Comment: @ForceBru Done... [this is the code...](http://paste.ofcode.org/gxY69rkVZeTpxDHjxuUYHf) I didnt use multiple spaces instead of tab.. Does space between if and bracket matter?

Comment: @pandik70, first, you have to add `:` after function declaration. Second, Python's code blocks are separated by alignment, or, to be precise, indentation (we use curly brackets in C/C++ and `BEGIN`/`END` in Pascal for this). Now, you can see that `retezec` in the first line of the function is misplaced: it sorta 'pops out' of the overall structure (in the link you posted it can be seen clearly). This is a problem.

Comment: Here you've used four spaces instead of one Tab symbol. Simply get rid of the spaces and insert a tab instead.

Comment: @pandik70, [This works fine](http://pastebin.com/T0ZwMBFC) (includes some code-style tips widely used among Python programmers)